# Powershell v2 :: Load a COM Interop DLL

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this DataLink DLL on my system - **Interop.MSDASC.dll** I am trying to load the same from Powershell like this -

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Interop.MSDASC.dll") | out-null
```

But, I get the following error -

```
Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MSDASC.dll' or one of its dependencies.  is not a 
valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)"
At line:1 char:32
+ [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile <<<< ("C:\Interop.MSDASC.dll") | out-null
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

How do I correctly load this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a 32 bit COM object and therefore you must load it from a 32 bit instance of PowerShell. To do this on a 64 bit version of Windows you can execute powershell.exe or powershell_ISE.exe in this folder:
%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWow64\windowspowershell\v1.0

And, this is the complete code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Interop.MSDASC.dll") 
$dataLinkInstance = new-object MSDASC.DataLinksClass
$dataLinkInstance.WriteStringToStorage("C:\\FrmPowershell.udl", "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;", 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just downloaded it from http://datadictionary.codeplex.com/ and load assembly in the same way you use and no issue come:

```
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile( "c:\Program Files\DataDictionaryCreator\Interop.MSDASC.dll")

GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v2.0.50727     c:\Program Files\DataDictionaryCreator\Interop.MSDASC.dll
```

Are you maybe on a x64 operative system?
if yes read here http://datadictionary.codeplex.com/workitem/28807

Comment: Are you telling in context of Powershell ?

Comment: Yes. Loaded assembly in powershell it's ok for me! I'm on windows 7 x86.

Comment: Cool. But, I do not have any .Net application as such. I am just directly trying to load the interop DLL. I am on Windows 7 64 Bit. I still cannot figure out why? Any clue ? I will try doing a regasm from Framework 32 folder such that it gets registered under WOW6432node ?

Comment: Have you try using powershell.exe for x86?  Path is: "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\\powershell.exe"

Comment: Good suggestion. I will try that tomorrow and update. But, how do we handle such scenario in production when the script will be invoked from C# app using POwershell Apis ?

Comment: The DLL loaded from "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\\powershell.exe

Answer (score -1):

```
$comInterOp = "C\Temp\Interop.YourAssembly.dll"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($comInterOp)
$yourClassObj = new-object YourAssembly.YourClassNameClass
$yourResult = $yourClassObj.YourMethod()
```

Comment: Please explain what you did and why you did it. At this point this answer is not instructive in helping the OP understand what to do.